# SQL joining on >=

Tags: sql

I have a table like this in ORACLE

```
a     b
--   --
1000   1
100    2
10     3
1      4
```

My other table has numbers like '67' or '112' in a column called numbers for example.
How can I join to this table using those values and get the correct result where >=1000 would be 1 and >= 100 would be 2 >=10 would be 3 etc.

I tried to do a

```
select g.b
from table o
join table2 g on o.column >= g.a
```

when I do this say 1002 was the value of g I would get the back these results.
    1
    2
    3
    4

when I just want 1

Comment: Maybe instead of joining that table you could just use a case statement. Unless there are many more comparison values than in your example.

Comment: There are that is the problem, and the table I am joining on is subject to change.  Which is why I am not using a case statement

Comment: `4-FLOOR(LEAST(3,LOG10(o.column)))`

Comment: I dare not submit that as an answer. I'll keep snark to the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using a subquery to get the `MAX` of column a, and then rejoining on the same table to get b:

```
select t.numericvalue, t2.b
from (
  select t.numericvalue, max(t2.a) maxb
  from table1 t
    join table2 t2 on t.numericvalue >= t2.a
  group by numericvalue
  ) t join table2 t2 on t.maxb = t2.a
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6471f/1)

Comment: @Josh -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be if your lookup table had ranges instead of just one number, such as row 1 = 1000,9999,1 and row 2 = 100,999,2 etc.
Then your join might be

```
SELECT OtherTable.n, lookup.b
from OtherTable
LEFT JOIN lookup on OtherTable.n between lookup.low and lookup.high
```

But, if you really want to use your original table, then on SQL Server, do this:

```
/*CREATE TABLE #A (a int,b int)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (1000,1),(100,2),(10,3),(1,4)

CREATE TABLE #B (n INT)
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (67),(112),(4),(2001)
*/
SELECT B.n,  A1.b
FROM #B B OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 a,b FROM #A A WHERE A.a<B.n ORDER BY A.a DESC) A1
```

Comment: Should have mentioned this is oracle, I like your answer though, I'll just have to adapt it and test it.